# Django: Changing the index site? (home page)

Tags: django, url, web

The index site on my Django homepage stopped working because of a problem that will take a very long time to fix. The site can't be down for that long so I am trying to change the index site so that if you go to the primary url you will atleast end up on the website.

What I have done is change the urls.py file in the primary application, where I simply replaced the line

```
url(r'^', include('news.urls', namespace='news')),
```

to

```
url(r'^', include('events.urls', namespace='events')),
```

in the urlpatterns list, where news is the faulty page and events is the page that I want to be shown. However, after pushing this to live nothing changed, and for some reason my local Django development server is not working.

Did I do anything wrong, or is there anything else I have to do as well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `news.urls` with `events.urls` may cause problems, if there are views/templates that try to reverse news urls. It would be better to leave the include as it is, and add a new URL pattern above that for the index:

```
from events.views import home

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', home, name='home'),
    url(r'^', include('news.urls', namespace='news')),
    ...
]
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but I don't quite understand what home is? What am I supposed to change in the events.views-file for this to work?

Comment: `home` is a view from your `events` app that you want to use for the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

In the events app make sure you have a URL such as 

    `......
    url(r'^$', views.EventsIndex.as_view(), name='index'),
    ......`

Comment: I have url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'), am I supposed to have both or should I replace this one?